# Android Turn on and off Sound App

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

I'm developing a game. I need a button to turn on and off game sounds.
In my app, I play background music which I want to be muted upon clicking a button. Here's my code:

```
AudioManager aManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

if (aManager.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) {
   aManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
} else {
   aManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
}
```

When I debug, the conditions are right but nothing happens! The sound is never turned off!

Answer (score 0):

Check for method "isVolumeFixed()". If true, your device can't have it's sound changed. Some devices have a policy about that.

Comment: and how can i fix this? what happens with every game that has that function? works in every device

Comment: Where is that method?